# How to integrate jahia with eclipse

Tags: jahia

I want to integrate jahia on eclipse.

i'm just starting to work with jahia and i do not know how to download her modules with maven

Need help, thank you!

Comment: tutorials is what you need to read.  See https://www.jahia.com/home/community/forum/jahia-user/jahia-install-forum/jahia-install-for-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for custom development then 
Here is the development intro

https://academy.jahia.com/documentation/digital-experience-manager/7.2/development/development-best-practices#INTRODUCTION

There are three parts template module and component

with maven jahia project can be created

https://academy.jahia.com/documentation/digital-experience-manager/7.2/development/osgi-module-development/building-a-new-osgi-module#Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Create a Module - Eclipse
• From Eclipse

```
In Eclipse, click on File > New > Other ... > Maven > Maven Project > Next.

Declare http://maven.jahia.org/maven2 as remote catalog and select it

Choose the archetype : jahia-module-archetype

Enter an artifactId (technical name), the jahiaVersion (7.1.0.0 for exemple) and the moduleName
```

For more information, see source:
https://academy.jahia.com/files/live/sites/academy/files/documentation/training/TR7_Basic-Developer_EN_V1.5.pdf 
(page 19 and following...)

Regards,